# Is it possible to create an xml subclass of a state list selector?

Tags: android

For example, say I have a color state list declared in XML, called **example1.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:color="@color/red"
        android:state_pressed="true" />

    <item
        android:color="@color/blue"
        android:state_checked="true" />

    <item
        android:color="@color/green"
        android:state_disabled="true" />

    <item
        android:color="@color/orange" />
</selector>
```

Then, I want to create **example2.xml** and I want it to be the exact same as **example1.xml** except I want the pressed color to be purple instead of red:

```
    <item
        android:color="@color/purple"
        android:state_pressed="true" />
```

So **example2.xml** would end up acting like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item
            android:color="@color/purple" <-- note this value is different
            android:state_pressed="true" />

        <item
            android:color="@color/blue"
            android:state_checked="true" />

        <item
            android:color="@color/green"
            android:state_disabled="true" />

        <item
            android:color="@color/orange" />
    </selector>
```

but without all of the duplicate code. Also, if I want to change a color I can just change it in one place.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this on Android, You have to create multiple xml resources for different selector.